# Why isn't this script that removes duplicate faces from voxel generated mesh not working?

Tags: procedural-generation, mesh

Hey this is my first post here. I'm trying to make a voxel world generation project for personal experience like minecraft like games. But I cannot find out why my script is not working as intended after I tried to implement a system to remove unnescessary faces when they are facing each other. The problem is that even though the script identifies that there is a neighbour block and no face should be generated I still get the faces in the mesh.
This is the code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

/*
 *0 = front
 *1 = right
 *2 = back
 *3 = left
 *4 = up
 *5 = down*/

public class ProceduralGen : MonoBehaviour
{
    //The chunk game object that stores the chunk's mesh. Atm i don't have infinite chunks as to keep things simpler till the basic script is done to move to the infinite chunk gen
    GameObject Chunk;

    //Array that stores the block's pos and other future data.
    Block[,,] blocks;

    //Current Chunks dimentions, the intended number would be 256 blocks of height but i'm keeping it small for performance and simplicity sake
    public int width = 10, height = 10, depth = 10;

    //A float that devides the coordinates on the world space in to a float between 0 and 1 so it fits the Mathf.Perlingnoise parameters
    public float res = 10f;

    //Mesh data
    List<Vector3> vertices;
    List<int> triangles;

    //Just a material to help view the generated Mesh
    public Material material;

    //This is an offset pos to help put the chunk at what a ever center i want
    public Vector3 offSetPos = new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);

    void Start()
    {
        BlockData.offSetPos = offSetPos;

        blocks = new Block[width, height, depth]; 

        Chunk = new GameObject("Cube", typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer)); //setting the chunk gameobject

        vertices = new List<Vector3>();
        triangles = new List<int>();


        //Starting to generate the chunk this will be put in a separated function in the future
        for (int z = 0; z < width; z++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                int y = GetHeight(x, z); // set the surface current block height based on perling noise
                MakeBlock(new Vector3Int(x, y, z)); 
            }
        }

        Chunk.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = material;

    }

    void MakeBlock(Vector3Int pos)
    {

        //Goes through a list of pre set vertices that defines how a block is made and makes a face and adds it's vertices to the vertices List
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            //Checks if there is a block at this face's direction or it's neighbour and makes the face but here is where it doesn't work anymore
            //despite the script point out there is a neighbour and it skipping the make face for this direction of the cube it still makes the face for some reason...
            if (!IsBlockAt(pos, i))
                MakeFace(pos, i);
        }

        UpdateMesh();
    }

    void MakeFace(Vector3Int pos, int dir)
    {
        //goes through each vertex inside the base cube vertices on BlockData and adds it to vertices array as well as triangulate those vertices based on an offset of vertices count - 4
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
                vertices.AddRange(BlockData.FaceVertices(i, pos));

                int offSet = vertices.Count - 4;

                triangles.Add(offSet + 0);
                triangles.Add(offSet + 1);
                triangles.Add(offSet + 2);
                triangles.Add(offSet + 0);
                triangles.Add(offSet + 2);
                triangles.Add(offSet + 3);
        }
    }

    bool IsBlockAt(Vector3Int pos, int dir)
    {
        // position helper ints that set's latter the position of the neighbour based on the direction the current face faces
        int x = pos.x, y = pos.y, z = pos.z;

        //setting the coordinates of the neighbour cube based on the direction
        if (dir == 0)
            z += 1;
        if (dir == 1)
            x += 1;
        if (dir == 2)
            z -= 1;
        if (dir == 3)
            x -= 1;
        if (dir == 4)
            y += 1;
        if (dir == 5)
            y -= 1;

        //Checks based on perling noise if there is supose to be a block in the 
        neighbour's coordinate, returns true if it's not air
        if (!(GetBlockAt(x, y, z) is Air))
            return true;

        //returns false if the last check was an air block
        return false;
    }

    int GetHeight(int x, int z)
    {
        //return perling noise height times the max height of the chunk based on 
        the block's coordinate devided by the resolution
        return (int)(Mathf.PerlinNoise((float)(x / res), (float)(z / res)) * height);
    }

    Block GetBlockAt(int x, int y, int z)
    {
        //Checks if the current block's height is lower then or the same as the perling noise at it's position if so there is a block if not there isn't
        if (GetHeight(x, z) <= y)
            return new Stone();
        else
            return new Air();
    }

    void UpdateMesh()
    {
        //Updates the mesh
        Mesh mesh = Chunk.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;

        mesh.vertices = vertices.ToArray();
        mesh.triangles = triangles.ToArray();
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    }


}
```

If needed I can put the other scripts in this post but i don't think it's necessary.
PS: Sorry for my bad english and bad spelling of words.

Comment: Did you notice that `MakeFace` always makes 6 faces, not just the one you tell it to make?

Comment: OMG i am so stuped as allways with coding most mistakes in ur code are gonna be like a missing , or ; or something as stuped as that in the logic. Thanks for pointing it out man and sorry for this but i don't know how to even reply to u directly in this post instead of making another comment.